# Выбор случайного значения, с последующем открытием страницы

Tags: html5

Есть сайт site.ru и есть три страницы сайта: site.ru/1, site.ru/2, site.ru/3. Мне нужно, чтобы при открытии site.ru/1, код случайным образом выбирал между site.ru/2  и site.ru/3 и автоматически перенаправлял пользователя на одну из этих страниц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать на бэкенде, на том языке, который вы используете.

Можно - на фронтенде в js. Примерно так:

```
window.location.href = "/" + getRandomInt(2, 3)

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Если хотите переходить на страницу, не меняя url - вместо `window.location.href = '...';` используйте `window.location.replace('...');`.

---

И главный вопрос - вам зачем это нужно? Проводите сплит-тестирование страниц? Для сплит-тестирования есть свои готовые и стабильно работающие инструменты.

Comment: Нет, не для сплит-тестирования, всё гораздо проще, это часть веб-игры. Большое спасибо за ответ, это как раз то, что мне нужно!